# Use of Defining Clauses

Tags: relative-clauses

> There are two men by the gate who keep a watch on it.

In the above sentence is there a problem?
One of my friends doesn't agree with the construction.
He says: 'who' should immediately be after the person mentioned. Yet, I believe 'by the gate' is the complement thus has nothing to do with 'who' in this sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is perfectly fine.

There is no rule or convention that says pronouns must come immediately after the noun they represent. There doesn't even need to be a referenced noun at all:

> **Who** is keeping a watch on the gate?

The pronoun can go anywhere at all so long, so long as it is syntactically sound:

> There are two men *at the gate*, wearing long jackets and drinking coffee, **who** keep a watch on it while they play Scrabble. There are also three men *at the hot dog stand*, standing around and not doing much, **who** look bored.

Answer (score 2):

> *There are two men by the gate who keep a watch on it.*

It's perfectly OK. The PP "by the gate" modifies "men" and hence is part of the nominal serving as antecedent for "who".

Note that it is also possible for a relative clause to occur in postposed position, at the end of the clause containing its antecedent:

*I met a man the other day who says he knows you*.

Examples like this, where the antecedent is separated form the relativised element by an adjunct, are OK provided there is no confusion as to what is the intended antecedent.